Examples of injectivity and surjectivity composition
I am trying to give examples of injectivity and surjectivity composition using g ◦ f. Do these seem like reasonable examples?
What is an example of a function that f: A → B and g : B → C such that g ◦ f is surjective, but f isn't.
If A = {1, 2}, B = {3}, and C = {4}. The function is f: A → B and g: B → C:

f (1) = f (2) = 3

g(3) = 4


g ◦ f is surjective because for every element in C, there exists an
element in A that maps to it.  f is not surjective as not all element
in B maps to an element in A
Find an example of functions f: A → B and g: B → C such that g ◦ f is injective,
but g isn’t.
If A = {1}, B = {2, 3}, and C = {4}. The function is f: A → B and g: B → C

f (1) = 2
g(2) = g(3) = 4

g ◦ f is injective because each element in A maps to an element in C.
g is not injective because multiple elements from B map to the same element in C

No...in your first case, $f$ is clearly surjective as all of $B$ is in the range of $f$.  It is not injective, of course.  Your second example is good.

For an example of the first type:  suppose $A={1}$, $B={2,3}$ and $C={4}$.  let $f(1)=2$ (and, of course, $g(2)=g(3)=4$).

A good way to think about surjectivity and injectivity side by side is to count preimages. For a map $f: A \to B$ and an arbitrary element $b \in B$, we ask about the preimage set
$$
f^{-1}({b}) = {a \in A \mid f(a) = b}.
$$
If this set has at least one element for any $b$ we start with, then $f$ is surjective. If this set has at most one element for any $b$ we start with, then $f$ is injective. And of course, if this set has exactly one element for any $b$ we start with, then $f$ is bijective.
